# pssh with sed and special characters

Tags: ssh, sed

I would like to run this sed:

```
sed "s?\(Defaults.*\)?\1:/etc/bla/foo/?" filename
```

But got failure, exited with error code 1 when running it as follow with pssh:

```
pssh -h /root/listofservers -l root -A "sed "s?\(Defaults.*\)?\1:/etc/bla/foo/?" filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

`pssh` has the following usage synopsis:

```
pssh [options] command ...
```

That is, don't quote the command that you want to execute on the remote hosts (or it will treat the whole quoted command as the name on the command). Also, single quote strings that are static, like the `sed` expression.

Suggestion:

```
pssh -h /root/listofservers -l root -A sed 's#\(Defaults.*\)#\1:/etc/bla/foo/#' filename
```

I have also changed `?` to `#` since `?` is a regular expression character.  It will not make a difference here, but it confused me briefly when I tried to parse the expression.